# Linq Query in Object Initializer

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code in an attempt to initialise the `List<OrderItem>` field of the `Order` I am instantiating. My problem is that Visual Studio does not like the innermost LINQ query; specifically, it is complaining about `from`, `i.Element("OrderItems")`, and `select`.

Is it not possible to initialise an object in this way, or am I just doing something incorrect? Thanks, Conor.

```
var orderXml = XDocument.Load("FileTest\\orders.xml");

orderXml.Descendants("Order").Do(i => orderList.Add(new Order()
{
    Customer = new Customer()
    {
        ID = new Guid(i.Element("Customer").Element("ID").Value)
    },

    OrderItems = new List<OrderItem>()
    {
        from current in i.Element("OrderItems")
        select new OrderItem() {
            Product = new Product()
            {
                ID = new Guid(current.Element("ID").Value),
                UnitPrice = current.Element("UnitPrice").Value.To<decimal>()
            },
            Quantity = current.Element("Quantity").Value.To<int>(),
            TotalPrice = current.Element("TotalPrice").Value.To<decimal>()
        }
    }
}));
```

Comment: What exactly Visual Studio does not like in innermost LINQ query? Is it font size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the object initializer for an `IEnumerable<T>` call add for each item in the list. However you can't suppy an `IEnumerable<T>` directly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx

Consider using the constructor instead.

```
 OrderItems = new List<OrderItem>(
    from current in i.Element("OrderItems")
    select new OrderItem() {
        Product = new Product()
        {
            ID = new Guid(current.Element("ID").Value),
            UnitPrice = current.Element("UnitPrice").Value.To<decimal>()
        },
        Quantity = current.Element("Quantity").Value.To<int>(),
        TotalPrice = current.Element("TotalPrice").Value.To<decimal>()
    }
 )
```

Comment: Nice catch, I didn't even notice that object initializer was used here